# How can I change the default animation behavior of a UIImageView when it is focused inside a UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: uiimageview, uicollectionviewcell, tvos

I have a `UICollectionViewController` and a `UIImageView` as an `IBOutlet` inside each cell. I set `imageView.adjustsImageWhenAncestorFocused = true` for the image views and when the related cell is focused, the image view gets too big. Just wondering if there is any way to control the animation behavior of the image view. I know I can override `didUpdateFocusInContext(_:withAnimationCoordinator:)`, but couldn't find out how to handle *hover* event.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So use `didUpdateFocusInContext` function to update your cell when focus on current selected cell.

First disable `adjustsImageWhenAncestorFocused` property for the image view then change size of imageview as per your wish.

Define two different sizes and use it for focused cell and rest of the cell.

```
CGSize originalCellSize = CGSizeMake(225, 354);
CGSize focusCellSize = CGSizeMake(240, 380);

- (void)didUpdateFocusInContext:(UIFocusUpdateContext *)context withAnimationCoordinator:(UIFocusAnimationCoordinator *)coordinator
{
    [coordinator addCoordinatedAnimations:^{
        if (self.focused) {
            self.imageView.frame.size = focusCellSize;
        } else {
            self.imageView.frame.size = originalCellSize;
        }
    } completion:nil];
}
```

Use `animatewithDuration:` to give better animation style when you changing cell size or use alpha or shadow effect for imageview for more perfect look.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a better solution is to handle this with CGAffineTransform on the cell (or contentView of the cell). This way you don't need to change view frames (you can also do the transform on the self.imageView.transform, if that's more suitable for you).

```
#pragma mark - UIFocusEnvironment

- (void)didUpdateFocusInContext:(UIFocusUpdateContext *)context withAnimationCoordinator:(UIFocusAnimationCoordinator *)coordinator {
    if (self.focused) {
        [coordinator addCoordinatedAnimations:^{
            self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.1f, 1.1f);
        } completion:nil];
    } else {
        [coordinator addCoordinatedAnimations:^ {
            self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.f, 1.f);
        } completion:nil];
    }
}
```